# HTML inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list that created using ng-repeat

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
```

All my items are text exept from one that suppose to be an image.
But the html of the image tag is not rendering and is representing as a string next to all of the text items.
Something like that:

1. Text
2. Text
3. Text
4. `<img src="...">`

There is some smart solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be an ng-bind-html-unsafe:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item"></li>
```

Here's an example of modifying the friends list example from the docs:
http://jsfiddle.net/UFZdF/4/

(btw- as the "unsafe" indicates, you really have to be careful that your items can't be uploaded or modified by untrusted parties who may want to add malicious links, iframes, javascript, etc.)